FPGA DDR timing constraints
I have EMMC master for FPGA. Please tell me how to write constraints on ports in DDR mode? I tried to write constraints but I doubt the correctness



Specification:
JEDEC Standard No.  84-B51
P.S. Here is another point: how to correctly take into account pcb delay in the final expression for output delay. This is what causes confusion

To help get an answer can you edit the question to specify which FPGA and design software is in use. Also, consider replacing the picture of the constraints with text for the reasons described in Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

I use vivado and board on base Artix Ultrascale+. When i write sdc, i oriented on the solution this issue:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630541/fpga-centric-timing-constraints
But author had EMMC slave
